# MySQL database for this case

Tags: mysql

I am really beginner when it's about databases and I am facing a problem.

I have a table with many rows. Each row got a primary key, called MY_KEY. MY_KEY is CHAR(20).

I have another table. Each row, **in one of the fields will have many MY_KEY separated by space and stored as TEXT, but never the same MY_KEY twice.**

---

I am not sure i explained this well, but how can I design those two tables to be more performance efficient?

My program will take the TEXT and add it to a vector and then binary search it. This will be slow if there are 1000 20 characters MY_KEY.

Comment: Don't store delimited values in the database! Normalize your data by introducing many-to-many table. Meanwhile you can post some sample data and explain your actual goal which you're trying to solve.

Comment: If my post is messy, please tell me what to explain better

Comment: @Blazer your post is fine, but your database design is dreadful. Read up on [database normalisation.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: I am sorry, I am just learning... Can you tell me the way to improve this design, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't store delimited values in the database! Normalize your data by introducing many-to-many table.

> Can you tell me the way to improve this design, please?

Your schema might look something like

```
CREATE TABLE table1 
(
  table1_key CHAR(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  -- other columns
);

CREATE TABLE table2
(
  table2_key CHAR(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  -- other columns
);

CREATE TABLE table2_table1 
(
  table2_key CHAR(20), 
  table1_key CHAR(20),
  PRIMARY KEY (table2_key, table1_key),
  FOREIGN KEY(table2_key) REFERENCES table2 (table2_key),
  FOREIGN KEY(table1_key) REFERENCES table1 (table1_key)
);
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3769)** demo

Comment: Thanks, a lot, this example made me understand a lot of things.

Comment: table1 is about 20 bytes per row, table2 is about 20 bytes per row, what's the size of table2_table1, please?

Comment: @Blazer You're welcome. 20 + 20 = 40 per row obviously

Comment: I see, so it's a speed boost on searches but a hit on size... Thank a lot!

Comment: Of course, if you have other columns as well, then you do not have to store them in table2_table1, so you are only storing the keys in table2_table1.

Answer (score 1):

Check out some readings on database normalization. The basic idea is that you don't want to have any column that stores more than one piece of data. While this isn't an absolute rule, it's a good rule of thumb, and will probably be more performant than what you're describing.

Instead of one row with a bunch of associated keys, consider having a bunch of rows with the pairs of associated keys. This is a superior way to represent a many to many relation in a relational database.  You can do a join to retrieve the data.

Comment: Is there a way to improve this by using `FOREIGN KEY`?

Comment: Yes, the foreign keys are the list in your example.